# Java custom method not working

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I'm starting to learn programming by doing some 
exercises...
Why this simple java code gives me an error?

```
class HelloWorldEdited {
    public int a = 5;
    public int b = 2;

    public static int sum() {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorldEdited obj = new HelloWorldEdited();

        System.out.println(obj.sum());
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Make sure to include all the relevant info when asking a question, otherwise people will be less inclined to answer your question. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: The first step in diagnosing and correcting an error is *always* reading the error message...

Comment: changing "public static int sum()" to "public int sum()" solve the problem, thank you for the advices. I'm going to read "how to ask"

Comment: `static` members belongs to "class" non-static members belong to instances. Lets say that you have many instances, like `new HelloWorldEdited(1,2);` and `new HelloWorldEdited(3,4);` which values `a` and `b` should be used when you call `HelloWorldEdited.sum()`? ... Compiler also don't know which is why it is forbidden in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's because you are accessing "non static" properties (a, b) from a static method (sum), this operation is forbidden.

Try to change

```
public static int sum()
```

to

```
public int sum()
```

To understand the "static" modifier I suggest you to read:
[official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

The method sum() is static. In this method you can't access variables "non static".